How to set image size in JTextPane with HTML and CSS (Java, Swing)?
I want to insert an image (say - a formula compiled from LaTeX) into JTextPane, using HTML+CSS for text markup, manually setting it's size. I tried like here
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;


public class App extends JFrame {

    private void run() {
        setSize(new Dimension(320, 240));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
        pane.setContentType("text/html");
        String imageUrl = getClass()
                              .getClassLoader()
                              .getResource("resources/img.jpg");
        pane.setText(
                "<html>"+
                    "<head> <style>"+
                            // CSS works perfectly for text,
                            ".text { color: red; font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; }"+
                            // but not for images
                            ".pic { width: 250px; }"+
                    "</style> </head>"+
                    "<body>"+
                        "<p class=\"text\"> Aaaa. </p>"+
                        "<img class=\"pic\" src=\""+imageUrl+"\" />"+
                    "</body>"+
                "</html>"
            );
        
        getContentPane().add(pane);
        setVisible(true);
    };

    public App() {
        super("Test HTML+CSS");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.run();
    }
}

For some reason JTextPane works perfectly with text styles, but ignores CSS notations for pictures. Is there any way to handle this out or I'm just wasting time?

Swing is very old and hasn't really been maintained. I'd avoid using it if you can

@Abra as I mentioned, Swing supports CSS for text, so I may just be doing something wrong. And I don't want to switch to JFX because I would have to rewrite a lot if I did.

I know, @ControlAltDel. The question is if Swing bad enough to leave it for JavaFX. I actually started with Swing because I didn't manage to compile JavaFX 8 for Arch at that point.

@ControlAltDel bug JDK-8187759 was fixed in the latest JDK release, i.e. 22.0.2, along with other Swing related bugs. Does that constitute hasn't really been maintained ?

Try putting the width in the img statement.  Java Swing works with up to HTML 3.2.

As Gilbert Le Blank mentioned in the comment, the width block shall be in <img> statement. So the HTML string should look like this:
<html>
  <body>
    <p color="red"> Aaaa. </p>
    <img width="250" src="/path/to/Image" />
  </body>
</html>

